# c# wpf datagrid can't add new row problem (load xml as dataset)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row, addition

sorry for that *easy problem* but i not understand why i can't get it alone...
I tried many different ways, bindings... but always the big thinks what i needed are not going together...
 now with that code 90% off my topics are going

*load items from xml file to datagrid

*change thinks

*save items back

*by select row - put the items out to txtbox + create buttons in a canvas

*loop throw all rows

**only to add some items in the datagrid without write it bevore directly to the xml-file iss not going jet...**

thats for now my code:

xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Data Id="1" Name="aaa" Height="25" Width="25" PosTop="25" PosLeft="25" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Timer_Clock.png" />
  <Data Id="2" Name="bbb" Height="25" Width="25" PosTop="100" PosLeft="25" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Timer_Clock.png" />
  <Data Id="3" Name="ccc" Height="44" Width="44" PosTop="25" PosLeft="200" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Timer_Clock.png" />
  <Data Id="4" Name="Se" Height="25" Width="25" PosTop="100" PosLeft="200" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Timer_Clock.png" />
  <Data Id="5" Name="aa54a" Height="25" Width="25" PosTop="50" PosLeft="25" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Fragezeichen.png" />
  <Data Id="6" Name="b54bb" Height="55" Width="55" PosTop="135" PosLeft="25" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Fragezeichen.png" />
  <Data Id="7" Name="csscc" Height="25" Width="25" PosTop="200" PosLeft="200" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Fragezeichen.png" />
  <Data Id="8" Name="Sh54e" Height="25" Width="25" PosTop="225" PosLeft="200" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Fragezeichen.png" />
  <Data Id="9" Name="aggaa" Height="55" Width="55" PosTop="25" PosLeft="300" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Picture.png" />
  <Data Id="10" Name="b45bffb" Height="25" Width="25" PosTop="100" PosLeft="325" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Picture.png" />
  <Data Id="11" Name="ccdc" Height="25" Width="25" PosTop="25" PosLeft="350" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Picture.png" />
  <Data Id="12" Name="S45fe" Height="55" Width="55" PosTop="100" PosLeft="300" Execute="MsPaint" Image="/Images/Picture.png" />
</DocumentElement>
```

xaml:  (i wrote that also with direct created Colums but my *load xml* not understand this)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1"   SelectionChanged="datagrid1_SelectionChanged" Background="LightGray" RowBackground="LightYellow" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="125" Margin="137,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="569">

</DataGrid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
 private void load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string load_xmlfileName = (txtbx_load_Name.Text + ".xml");

            try
            {
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Data");
                dataSet.ReadXml(load_xmlfileName);
                datagrid1.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =" + (ex));
            }
        }

        private void save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string save_xmlfileName = (txtbx_save_Name.Text + ".xml");

            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
                dt = ((DataView)datagrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable();  //DataView

                string XmlFile = (save_xmlfileName);

                dt.WriteXml(XmlFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =" + (ex));
            }
        }

 private void del_all_in_DatagridList(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try { 
                    datagrid1.ItemsSource = null;
                    //datagrid1.Columns.Clear();
                    //datagrid1.Items.Clear();
                    datagrid1.Items.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =" + (ex));
            }

 private void loop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (System.Data.DataRowView dr in datagrid1.ItemsSource)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());
                    txtbx_outbox_Id.Text = (dr[0].ToString());
                    txtbx_outbox_Name.Text = (dr[1].ToString());
                    txtbx_outbox_Height.Text = (dr[2].ToString());
                    txtbx_outbox_Width.Text = (dr[3].ToString());
                    txtbx_outbox_PosTop.Text = (dr[4].ToString());
                    txtbx_outbox_PosLeft.Text = (dr[5].ToString());
                    txtbx_outbox_Execute.Text = (dr[6].ToString());
                    txtbx_outbox_Image.Text = (dr[7].ToString());

                    //Thread.Sleep(500); //o,5 Sec

                    //-------------springe zu *Logging_Sys_Start*----------------------
                    string Sender = "";
                    Create_Button_Click(Sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("loop Error-Handling =\r\n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

// *************** now the Problem Codes *******************************************************
// **********************************************************************************************

 private void New_Datagrid_Row_v1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Data");
                //table1.Columns.Add("id");
                //table1.Columns.Add("Name");
                //table1.Columns.Add("Age");
                //table1.Rows.Add(1, "Jack", 18);
                table1.Rows.Add(2, "Tim", 18);

                // this.datagrid1.ItemsSource = table1;


                DataSet set = new DataSet("Data");
                set.Tables.Add(table1);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =" + (ex));
                // *****************  * error array longer as the table colums* *************
            }      
        }
        private void New_Datagrid_Row_v2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable("Data");
                table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
                table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("HeightWidt", typeof(int));
                table.Columns.Add("PosTop", typeof(int));
                table.Columns.Add("PosLeft", typeof(int));
                table.Columns.Add("Execute", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(string));

                table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", 24, 100, 35, "Notepad", "Images / Timer_Clock.png");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =" + (ex));
                // ***********  *no error - do nothing* ****************
            }
        }

 private void New_Datagrid_Row_v3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string Id = "7";
                string Name = "HeyHo";
                string Height = "22";
                string Width = "22";
                string PosTop = "44";
                string PosLeft = "44";
                string Execute = "Explorer";
                string Image = "/Images/Picture.png";

                DataTable dft = new DataTable();

                // DataColumn column;
                DataRow row;
                DataView view;


                    row = dft.NewRow();
                    row["Id"] = Id;
                    row["Name"] = Name;
                    row["Height"] = Height;
                    row["Width"] = Width;
                    row["PosTop"] = PosTop;
                    row["PosLeft"] = PosLeft;
                    row["Execute"] = Execute;
                    row["Image"] = Image;

                    dft.Rows.Add(row);


                    view = new DataView(dft);
                    datagrid1.ItemsSource = view;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =\r\n" + ex.Message);
                // **********************  *error Colum "ID" iss not in the table *  ********
            }


        }

        private void New_Datagrid_Row_v4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
                dt.Columns.Add("id", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                dt.Columns.Add("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "a";
                dr[1] = "abc";
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =\r\n" + ex.Message);
                // *********  *no error - delete all exist rows + make a new row **********
            }

        }
        private void New_Datagrid_Row_v5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
                // Method 1 
                dt.Columns.Add("column0", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                // Method 2 
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("column1", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["column0"] = "AX";
                dr["column1"] = true;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                // Doesn't initialize the row 
                DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =\r\n" + ex.Message);
                // ****************************** Nothing *******************
            }
        }
        private void New_Datagrid_Row_v6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
                // dt.Columns.Add("id");
                //dt.Columns.Add("Name");

                int Id = 7;
                string Name = "HeyHo";
                int Height = 22;
                int Width = 22;
                int PosTop = 44;
                int PosLeft = 44;
                string Execute = "Explorer";
                string Image = "/Images/Picture.png";


                dt.Rows.Add(Id, Name, Height, Width, PosTop, PosLeft, Execute, Image);
                datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =\r\n" + ex.Message);
                // *****************  * error array longer as the table colums* ***********
            }

        }
```

**Error Replay=**

**New_Datagrid_Row_v1       * error array longer as the table colums * **

**New_Datagrid_Row_v2   * no error - nothing * **

**New_Datagrid_Row_v3       * error Colum "ID" iss not in the table * **

**New_Datagrid_Row_v4       * no error - delete all exist rows + make a new row * **

**New_Datagrid_Row_v5       * nothing * **

**New_Datagrid_Row_v6       * error array longer as the table colums * **

... so that's all what i have.... i tried also bindings so i make a collection - can add easy new rows but then i can't load - save it to xml-files - or i can't friggerout how to do this....

my big project is in c# wpf but without bindings and mvvm - so for now i need a easy way to do thst that i can include that workset - later i wont to go more to bindings an mvvm but for now its to much to rewrite....

**i think my big problem iss i load all in a dataset (Name??-is catched from my xml-file) and from that i need to catch that --Stream whatever-- and put into that set the new data but i not understand how i can do that... ore other way i need to copy the hole table-items and in that sequence i put that new dataset in and put it again to the table...**

thanks 4all help :-)

mfg

AndyK

Comment: I can't understand the wording of the question at all. Could you try to reduce it down to a minimal, verifiable example and state clearly what result you expect and what result you are getting?

Comment: The XAML needs to define the columns.  You have no columns and that is causing the exception : https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/

Answer (score 0):

@ jdweng =

xaml define colums= yes i maked that bevore but then my *load xml* not understand that

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1"   SelectionChanged="datagrid1_SelectionChanged" Background="LightGray" RowBackground="LightYellow" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="125" Margin="137,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="569">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Height" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Width" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PosTop" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PosLeft" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Execute" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Image" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

See image **c#_datagrid_xml_load_without_declare_colums_bevore**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hUXJ.png)

See image **c#_datagrid_xml_load_without_declare_colums_after**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdz8P.png)

See image **c#_datagrid_xml_load_with_declare_colums_bevore**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAMcZ.png)

See image **c#_datagrid_xml_load_with_declare_colums_after**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjK4n.png)

hopefull you can see the pictures...

- when i add the colums in the xaml then my xml-load packing the items not in the matrix - next to them....
  -when i not add colums in the xaml then my xml-load make his one matrix and it works fine....
  thats the reason why i not create the colums bevore in the xaml....

yes i know that link/page - i test that example bevore but i had the problem that i can´t
load save a xml-file throw that....

@  Crowcoder =   easy question - sorry for my bad english....

**i need to add a new row but the error message come up**

```
 private void New_Datagrid_Row_v6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
                // dt.Columns.Add("id");
                //dt.Columns.Add("Name");

                int Id = 7;
                string Name = "HeyHo";
                int Height = 22;
                int Width = 22;
                int PosTop = 44;
                int PosLeft = 44;
                string Execute = "Explorer";
                string Image = "/Images/Picture.png";


                dt.Rows.Add(Id, Name, Height, Width, PosTop, PosLeft, Execute, Image);
                datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error =\r\n" + ex.Message);
                // *****************  * error array longer as the table colums* *******************************
            }

        }
```

i have 8 colums and i say i make a new row with 8 colums but the error 
**error array longer as the table colums**

come up - what should i doo?

thanks for help :-)